# Memcache eviction monitoring system

Tags: algorithm, mongodb, optimization, memcached

The memcached evicts data slab wise due to which the LRU is running on the respective size slabs. Therefore even if the free space is available in the memcache, keys are being evicted.

I want to build a monitoring system to check which keys are being evicted prematurely due to the slabing algorithm.
I am thinking of creating a system to hit the memcached at regular intervals for all the keys inserted in to the memcached. I have a logging system already which records all the insertion keys into the memcache, this log data is stored in mongo.

Please suggest if i am correct in my approach or any better alternative ?

Comment: Looks relevant: http://dblab.usc.edu/users/papers/CAMPTR.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about your approach only, it is correct as its workable. But the problem is, this method can hurt the performance of your app as it is continually hitting the Memcache and fetching the keys.

As far as alternatives are concerned, There can be three alternative eviction policies are there,

1) Least Frequently Used

2) Least Recently Used

3) Priority based Eviction

These are the eviction policies offered by **NCache** which is an enterprise level distributed cache for .NET and Java and also provides a fast and reliable storage for ASP.NET and JSP Sessions. To learn more about these eviction policies, please check the following  link,

http://www.alachisoft.com/resources/docs/ncache/help-4-1/eviction-policy.html?mw=NDE2&st=MQ==&sct=NTAw&ms=CQYAAAABAAAAACIBBAQC